# Odoo filestore missing

Tags: odoo-14

I want to set up a new Odoo development instance in a docker container with data from the live instance (running outside of docker).

To copy the database inside the docker container I followed these steps:

```
sudo docker cp dump.sql db_docker_name:/dump.sql  

sudo docker exec -it --user postgres db_docker_name /bin/bash 

psql database_name < dump.sql  

ALTER DATABASE database_name OWNER TO odoo; 

sudo docker exec docker_name pip3 install xmlschema # and all the other requirements
```

I get the error:

```
2022-10-17 08:10:29,024 1 INFO dblive odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /var/lib/odoo/filestore/dblive/6a/6ad87633490735f27b4f73d8d984193d8d7d6947 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(52,).datas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None,)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(52,).raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 102, in _file_read
    with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/odoo/filestore/dblive/6a/6ad87633490735f27b4f73d8d984193d8d7d6947'
```

Inside the container I have these files:

```
odoo@95198003ea0a:~/filestore/dblive$ ls
16  18  86  checklist  d0  e7  fa
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by copying the original filestore into the new one.

```
docker cp filestore/. dev_odoo_1:/var/lib/odoo/filestore/dblive
```